# ##[error]Error: NO JSON file matched with specific pattern: **/appsettings.json

Tags: json, azure-devops, azure-appservice, variable-substitution

I'm trying to deploy an `Azure App Service` using `Azure Devops`.

I'm using the Task `Azure App Service deploy` version `4.*`

I started noticing the following error in the log recently with the deployment failing (saw it first on 24th September)

```
Applying JSON variable substitution for **/appsettings.json
##[error]Error: NO JSON file matched with specific pattern: **/appsettings.json.
```

In the pipeline I use the task `Extract files` to extract `*.zip`, then use the result to search for `**/appsettings.json`.

The same task was running fine till a few days ago.
I tried redeploying an old release which was successful earlier, but it failed now with the same above error.

I double checked, there was no changes done in the pipeline recently for this to break.

How can I fix this.

Comment: Is it possible to share your complete pipeline definition? Recently we made some changes to the task which would result in this issue, sharing complete pipeline definition would be much better to locate the cause and the solution. Are you using this App deploy task in release pipeline? Have you used Extract task before the app deploy task in your release pipeline?

Comment: Thanks @MerlinLiang-MSFT for the comment. I figured the issue was with `Extract files` task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my issue was not with the task `Azure App Service deploy`, but with the task `Extract Files`.

A rough look on my pipeline is as below:

### Before the fix

> 1. Extract files
>    [image]
> 2. Deploy Azure App Service
>    [image]

The `JSON variable substitution` failed because the `Extract files` task was not able to find `*.zip` files in the root folder and hence extracted nothing. So, there was no `appsettings.json` file in the folder structure at all.

### The Fix

- Update the `Extract files` task search pattern as `**/*.zip`

Now my pipeline looks like below.

> 1. Extract files
>    [image]
> 2. Deploy Azure App Service
>    [image]

It now works fine for me.